# Custom ClaimsIdentity in Owin authentication pipeline

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, wif

I've got a small ASP.NET MVC5 project.
I setup Owin with the following code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataSerializers.Ticket = new CustomTicketSerializer<CustomClaimsIdentity>();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxx",
                Authority = "xxx",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "xxx",
                RedirectUri = "xxx",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The `CustomTicketSerializer` returns a `CustomClaimsIdentity` object instead of the usual `ClaimsIdentity`

The `CustomClaimsIdentity` extends `ClaimsIdentity`

If I inspect the `User` property in my `HomeController` the type is `ClaimsIdentity` istead of the expected `CustomClaimsIdentity` even if I verified during the debugging that the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` returns an `AuthenticationTicket` containing an identity with type `CustomClaimsIdentity`.
Seems something is changed by Owin pipeline but I don't understand where.
Any idea?

Comment: A ClaimsPrincipal can have multiple Identities. 'Identity' gives you the primary one. Try looking in User.Identities (plural).

Comment: You're compeletly right. In fact there is one identity of type `CustomClaimsIdentity`. Thank you